# How to handle "Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, binance

I know there are many similar topics, but still I'm confused to solve this, I wanted to read balances and rates from the API, but either I get pending/timeout error or UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Message, how to usually handle this error in Node js, Thanks

```
  binance.balance((error, balances) => {
  if ( error ) return console.error(error);
  var keyN = Object.keys(balances);
  let coincount = keyN.length;  //406
  var StBalance = JSON.stringify(balances);
  var PsBalance = JSON.parse(StBalance); 

  
  
  async function bAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < coincount ; i++) {  
          var coinName = keyN[i];
          var coinBalance = Object.values(PsBalance[coinName])[0];  
          
              var myPair = keyN[i]+'USDT';
              let ticker =  await binance.prices(myPair) ;
              let cRate = Number(Object.values(ticker));
              console.info('Rate of ',myPair,': ',cRate); 
              console.info('balance of ',coinName,': ', coinBalance);
              console.info('Value of ',coinName,' amount to USDT',cRate*coinBalance);
          
    
    }
} 
  bAll();
});
```

Comment: A callback function pattern mixed with the promise pattern is going to be a pain. Anyway you need to catch the error, either chaining a `.catch` to the promise you get from `bAll()`, or by adding a `try..catch` block.

Comment: `bAll().catch(err => { console.log(err)})`